# Receiving "EPROTO" when HTTPS requests with Node 10

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, next.js, vercel

a few days ago i moved my frontend with NextJS to Vercel and i started experiencing this following intermittent error during build and production server. So i searched all over the internet but i cannot find the solution.

I am receiving the following error when my App tries to make HTTPS request:

```
Compiled successfully.
09:47:13.026    Automatically optimizing pages...
09:47:15.212    Error at BlogService.getRecentPosts, details: Error: request to https://**masked** failed, reason: write EPROTO 140256911292224:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1550:SSL alert number 80
09:47:16.629    Error at getStaticProps on Homepage, details: Error: write EPROTO 140657767638848:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1550:SSL alert number 80
09:47:16.654    Error at BlogService.getRecentPosts, details: Error: request to https:/**masked** failed, reason: write EPROTO 139955108906816:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1550:SSL alert number 80
```

The backend destination is using a Nginx with Reverse Proxy with LetsEncrypt Certificate

So anybody can help me? I never experienced this issue

**UPDATE**

I changed my backend to AWS Api Gateway but the issue remains.
I already changed my frontend to just make Https requests using TLS 1.2, and the error remains intermittent

Anybody help me?